# Laravel retuns me empty response on login user but over postman it works well

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, postman

I updated laravel from 5.7 to 5.8. All works ok using postman, but when I publish it into AWS it still works over postman but using vuejs app it returns 200 but without any return body. One more thing that I change is routes file - split them into multiple files but it works over postman, as I mention.

I try to add `dd("TEST")` and I get it over postman but over vuejs app it still nothing. Can anybody have idea what can be the issue?

I try with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan route:clear` but without any progress.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution so maybe someone will be helpful:

I add this awesome package `barryvdh/laravel-cors` and add it into api middleware because I saw that in Firefox shows not valid Origin, that error I didn't get using Chrome. And that solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Compare headers of request send by Postman and browser. Especially check `ACCEPT` parametr.